# getting/setting browser_id with Products.BeakerSessionDataManager

Tags: session, cookies, plone, plone-5.x

I'm having a problem associating a browser_id to a session when using Products.BeakerSessionDataManager.  I'm working on Plone 5.

As far as I understand Zope sessions, as soon as `.getSessionData()` is called on a session data manager, a session data container is created if it did not exist.  Furthermore, this data will contain a `token`, which is the same as the `browser_id` associated with the browser making the request.  And finally, a cookie is set on the response with the name `_ZopeId` (and the value is the same as the `token`).  Thus, when I use the default session data manager that come with Zope, I get this:

`ipdb> context.session_data_manager.getSessionData()
id: 14737473151418102847, token: 38878600A7nh90DE9ao, content keys: []`

However, when I use Products.BeakerSessionDataManager, the same call gives me this:

`ipdb> context.session_data_manager.getSessionData()
{'_accessed_time': 1473745441.437582, '_creation_time': 1473745441.437582}`

Moreover, **no cookie is set**.

Perusing some [old Zope docs](http://old.zope.org/Documentation/Books/ZopeBook/2_6Edition/Sessions.stx.1), I found a reference to `getContainerKey()`, so I thought that might get me the browser_id.  However, the returned value is different on every request, so that does not work.  Also, calling `.getBrowserIdManager().getBrowserId()` on the `session_data_manager` throws an error, because Beaker does not support browser id managers.

I want to set a cookie, and I want a token. I'm doing this so that I can identify anonymous clients in a voting application, so that they will not cast multiple votes (at least not in the same session - there are other mechanisms to allow voting only when certain other conditions are met).

Am I misunderstanding the machinery, or am I missing something?